# If we have a number with n bits, can we remove a bit such that the remaining number tells us which bit we removed?

Tags: algorithm, bit

while solving a computer science problem, I came up with this question. I would like to find an algorithm to, given a number with n bits, I remove a bit such that the number formed by the other n-1 bits (in the same order) tell us whether the removed bit is a 0 or an 1.

For instance, if n = 7, if it is given the number 0110101, I must be able to choose a bit such that the remaining number tells me if the removed bit is a 0 or an 1. If the number 010101 corresponds to an 1, then I can remove the second (or the third) bit from 0110101 and, with the remaining number (010101) i would know that I removed an 1.

If I found a correspondence between each number of n-1 bits and a 0 or a 1 such that for every n-bit number I am able to remove a bit that is the correspondent of the remaining (n-1)-bit number, I would have the problem solved, but I still couldn't find such a correspondence. May anyone if there is such a correspondece and what is the correspondence, please?

Comment: you mean something like the [hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code)?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot figure out how can I use hamming code here. Can you explain, please? (In this case the 'sent message' will be one bit smaller than the 'original message', and the only thing the receiver needs to discover is whether the removed bit is a 0 or a 1.)

Comment: Solve some edge cases first. Say, n = 1. There are two numbers of length n=1, `0` and `1`. Take either of these numbers and remove a bit you want (there's only one). You are left with an empty set of bits. Can you tell, looking at an empty space, what was removed from there?

Comment: No, i think it's not possible for the case n=1... So what I am asking is impossible for all n?

Comment: If this were possible you'd have an incredible compression algorithm :D. If this is some code challenge, then maybe you missed a detail. If it is, please quote the challenge literally. For instance, if you *know* the original number and the number with one bit removed, then it is of course possible to tell whether a 0 or a 1 was removed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not exist a unique "correspondence" between all n-bit numbers and all n-1 bit numbers. So the algorithm in question cannot exist with the given parameters.

Observe: (My apologies for the notation. I'm just getting started on stack overflow and have yet to learn how to use nice symbols [specifically those used in set theory would have been helpful])

Let **A** be the set of all n-bit numbers. Let **X** be the set of all n-1 bit numbers which are obtained by removing a 1 from all elements in set **A**. Let **Y** be the set of all n-1 bit numbers which are obtained by removing a 0  from all elements in set **A**.

Now, suppose we have an n-1 bit value **b**. We would like to determine whether **b** belongs in the set **X** or the set **Y**, and note that it cannot be in both (your algorithm). The only way this would be able to work is if the intersection of **X** and **Y** is empty.

So, we can prove that the intersection of **X** and **Y** is not empty by showing that there exists some n-1 bit value **z** where **z** is an element in **X** and **z** is an element in **Y**.

Let **z** be the n-1 bit number 11010. To obtain **z** in **X** we start with the n-bit value in **A** 110110, then we remove a 1 to obtain 11010 (which is **z**), which by our definition of set **X** it belongs in set **X**. So, **z**=11010 is an element of **X**.

Let **z** be the n-1 bit number 11010. To obtain **z** in **Y** we start with the n-bit value in **A** 110010, then we remove a 0 to obtain 11010 (which is **z**), which by our definition of set **Y** it belongs in set **Y**. So, **z**=11010 is an element of **Y**.

Since we can see that there exists a value **z** which is an element of **X** and an element of **Y**, we can see that the intersection of **X** and **Y** cannot be empty. Therefore, the algorithm in question cannot exist as there is no unique relation.

Answer (score 0):

if you are only looking at it from the perspective of one bit missing, tell if it was 0 or 1, simple parity should solve your case...

parity is just: agree upon either having an even amount of 1 bits or an odd amount

given any N bit number, count the bits that are one and add a new bit so the resulting number either has an even or odd amount of 1 bits

now if one bit is deleted you can simply count the number of 1 bits... say you are running even parity... if your number has an even number of 1s, a 0 was deleted, else it was a 1

parity itself will not tell you **if** a bit was removed
but knowing that it was removed, parity can answer if it was a 0 or 1

example with numbers:

```
initial number: 0110101  
even parity:    01101010 (we add a 0 because there were 4 1s)  
delete a bit:     x  
                0101010
count parity -> 3 -> odd -> we are on even parity -> a 1 was removed
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and It makes sense to me, however I have a problem: in my case, I cannot add a new bit (the final number should really have n-1 bits...) Is it still possible to use the simple parity method?

Comment: if you are unable to store information along the n bit number, and there's no further restrictions to that n bit number, you are out of luck...